# How to determine version auto-launch from regedit?

Tags: registry, version, launch

I am a software support geoscientist and my coders are not helping me with this question, hoping you can help.

Our software can auto-launch when you open a project file (sort of like when you open a spreadsheet, Excel automatically opens it). When the software is installed, one of the yes/no prompts is to use that particular version to perform the auto-launch. This will override any previous auto-launch assignment as only one version can launch the project.

I have been directed to the registry editor > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rok (which is our project file type) but it only contains: the description, not the file type.

[image: Image of registry editor with key]

Is there a location in which the specific launch version is specified?

Thanks!
Monica

Answer (score 0):

Try this registry.

Find the file extension in question under this key in the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts

You may also need to look at the same sub key from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found in here the folders 'OpenWithList' and 'OpenWithProgids'. Within 'OpenWithList' the RokDoc.bat file is listed, however this is the name of the launch file for all of the versions. Additionally, they are all completely identical!

Answer (score 0):

Using the content of the image, you just need to continue down the same registry tree (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) to find `rok_auto_file`, which will give you information on what the default actions are for that file type and what opens it.

However, the quickest way is usually from a command prompt. Here's an example using a Word document (.doc extension); you can replace the .doc with .rok and follow the example easily enough.

First, find out what .doc file is associated with

```
C:\Users\Ken>assoc *.doc
```

Outputs

```
.doc=Word.Document.8
```

Now find out what file type a *Word.Document.8* is using ftype.exe

```
C:\Users\Ken>ftype Word.Document.8
```

Outputs

```
Word.Document.8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /n /dde
```

Comment: HI Ken, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately the output is "File association not found for extension *.rok". I tried running the command prompt as admin, but still nothing.

Comment: @n00bMonica: That can't be correct, because the image shows that you have an association for .rok files (they're associated with `rok_auto_file`). So either your image isn't from the machine you're running `assoc` on, or you've made a mistake when running `assoc`.

Comment: I tried it again, as my user and as admin. I've installed the software under my username. Running 'assoc' works for .doc, .xlsx, .csv, but nothing for .rok. Running 'ftype' works for the outputs from the three aforemented types, but not for 'rok_auto_file'. Is there another place on my computer this could be assigned, if it's not under admin (system32) or my own username? Other usernames exist, but the software was installed when logged into my username.

Comment: What is the full key name from the registry key you posted? (It's shown in the RegEdit status bar when you've got that key selected.) The image appears to show HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, which means it's registered globally. It may be HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead, in which case it's only for the user currently logged in when RegEdit was started.

Comment: the status bar says 'Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rok'.

Comment: Then it's globally available, which means that ftype and assoc will work if the file association exists on your machine. I can't explain why they're not.